# Scala with cats IO/Either instead of Future/Exceptions

Tags: scala, cats-effect

I'm in the process of adopting `IO`/`Either` to replace `Future`/`Exception`'s where applicable, but I need help with the following code:

```scala
// some Java library
def dbLoad(id: Int): Int = {
  throw new Exception("db exception")
}

// my scala code
sealed trait DbError extends Exception with Product

object DbError {
  case object SomeError extends DbError
}

val load: Int => IO[Either[DbError, Int]] = { id =>
  IO.fromFuture { IO { Future {
    try { Right(dbLoad(id)) } catch { case NonFatal(e) => Left(SomeError) }
  } } }
}

val loadAll: IO[Either[DbError, (Int, Int, Int)]] =
  for {
    i1 <- load(1)
    i2 <- // call 'load' passing i1 as parameter, if i1 is 'right'
    i3 <- // call 'load' passing i2 as parameter, if i2 is 'right'
  } yield (i1, i2, i3) match {
    case (Right(i1), Right(i2), Right(i3)) => Right((i1, i2, i3))
    case _ => Left(SomeError)
  }
```

I have not been able to get it working/compiling correctly, could you please help me understand:

1. how can I avoid executing subsequent calls to `load` (in `loadAll`) if a `Left` is detected?
2. if a call to `load` is successful, how can I use its `right` value for the following call to `load`?
3. is this the right approach to do it? Would you implement it in a different way?

Thanks everyone

Comment: You may want to take a look at `EitherT` however, what most folks do is just sallow the exception in the error channel of `IO` so instead of `IO[Either[DbError, Int]]` you would only have `IO[Int]` and then you will use operations like `recoverWith` or `onError` to manage those exceptions. - Feel free to drop to [**typelevel discord** server](https://discord.gg/a9gwu6U6) to discuss this in more detail.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez  It seems like `EitherT` is what I'm looking for. I'm going to try that approach first since I'm trying to reduce the number of exceptions thrown. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me first put up the code that I think gets you what you want, and how typically things like this might be approached, I'll then describe what and why, and maybe some other suggestions:

```scala
import cats.data.EitherT
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.implicits._
import com.example.StackOverflow.DbError.SomeError

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.control.NonFatal
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object StackOverflow {
  // some Java library
  def dbLoad(id: Int): Int = {
    throw new Exception("db exception")
  }

  // my scala code
  sealed trait DbError extends Exception with Product

  object DbError {
    case object SomeError extends DbError
  }

  val load: Int => IO[Either[DbError, Int]] = { id =>
    IO.fromFuture(
      IO(
        Future(dbLoad(id))
          .map(Right(_))
          .recover {
            case NonFatal(_) => Left(SomeError)
          }
      )
    )
  }

  val loadAll: EitherT[IO, DbError, (Int, Int, Int)] =
    for {
      i1 <- EitherT(load(1))
      i2 <- EitherT(load(i1))
      i3 <- EitherT(load(i2))
    } yield (i1, i2, i3)

  val x: IO[Either[DbError, (Int, Int, Int)]] = loadAll.value
}
```

First, rather than try-catch inside the `IO[Future[_]]`, Future itself has a number of combinators that can help you manage errors, assuming you have some control over what you get back.

[For-comprehensions](https://medium.com/@hengquan/scala-for-comprehension-tricks-9c8b9fe31778) in Scala when applied in this fashion "short circuit" so if the first call to `load(1)` fails with a left then the rest of the comprehension won't execute. The use of `EitherT` allows you to manage the fact that your `Either` is "wrapped" in an effect type.

There are some problems with this approach, specifically around variance, you can read about them here:

http://www.beyondthelines.net/programming/the-problem-with-eithert/

There are also some performance implications for using this pattern that you may want to consider